# perfmon counter for .NET socket that shows receive buffer status

Tags: .net, sockets, udp, perfmon

Does anyone know a counter in perfmon.exe that will show the number of bytes that are buffered for a .NET socket?  I'm hoping to see some trends while reading in mass amounds of UDP packets.